# What does the button "Gamer Chat" mean?

Tags: button, chat, facebook-canvas

I found one unknown for me button: Gamer Chat in Facebook App Dashboard. 
What does this Button mean? What if do I unable it? What can it cause? Here is a screen http://screencast.com/t/MWcmqaPn

Regards, 
Victoria

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gamer chat on the right side of your game. The whole service is in beta, so it is available only for USA and Canada (I guess). Also, there might be some other restrictions.

Comment: Hi Maria, 
Thanks  a lot for the answer!
Do you mean this chat http://screencast.com/t/NuV9PCSdHK8 ?